# Can anyone identify this Decepticon toy?

Tags: character-identification, transformers, toys

My brother found this toy at a second-hand shop, but we weren't able to identify it.

It has a Decepticon logo inside the round hole on the front (middle chest, in the robot form) and is most likely missing some pieces.

[image: Vehicle form]

[image: Robot form]

Does anyone know where it comes from?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like that character is **[Snow Cat](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Snow_Cat_(Energon))**, a Decepticon from *[Transformers: Energon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_Energon_(franchise))*, which was a follow-up to *[Transformers: Armada](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_Armada_(franchise))*.

> Snow Cat is a powerful Decepticon who can overcome any environment. He transforms into an all-terrain vehicle and has given his Decepticon allies a strategic advantage in battle on many occasions. Though unruly at times, Snow Cat has proven to be one of Megatron's most valued warriors. His insane fighting tactics are feared by his enemies, and sometimes, his allies.

[image: Image of the official Snow Cat toy and packaging.]